# Got this Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I was running this program to display SVG image

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Expo from './assets/check-mark.svg';
import SVG from 'react-native-svg';

export default class MyApp extends Component {
 render(){
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor:"black"}}>
    <Expo width={20}
    height={15} />
    </View>
   );
 }
}
```

and came across this error `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.`

How can I resolve this?
or is there any other better approach to use SVG image is React Native?

Comment: Did you try to set width and height as strings? width="20" height="15"

Comment: Tried, but no use. Still showing the same error

Comment: don't forget to cd ios && pod install to make it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to display an SVG in react-native(according to me, this is the best and easy method) is:

First install this SVG package:
[npm i react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)

Secondly,

- Download the SVG image you need.
- Open that SVG file as a text file
- Copy the code from the SVG file and paste it into the below site
- https://react-svgr.com/playground/
- Check the check box against React Native on the left side of the website
- You will get a code on the right side "JSX OUTPUT"
- Now in your project's asset folder (or wherever you want to save that SVG), create a new JS file and copy-paste the code you got from the "JSX OUTPUT"  side.
- Save this file and use it as a custom component in your project.

PS: No need to install the SVG transformer package

Answer (score 12):

For svg files react-native-svg [suggests](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#use-with-svg-files) the usage of [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer).

install the package:

```
yarn add --dev react-native-svg-transformer
```

add the configuration to `metro.config.js`:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```

With that your you should be able to render your SVG files.

Answer (score 9):

1. Check `metro.config.js` file

```js
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```

2. Stop metro bundler or clear metro bundler cache
3. Rebuild the app again using `yarn run ios`

Answer (score 4):

> I was facing the same problem after installing all the required
> package. But after stopping metro bundler and rebuilding the project
> my issue automatically resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for expo

1_ install react native svg transformer
npm i --save-dev react-native-svg-transformer and
npm i react-native-svg

2_ in **metro.config.js** file

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"]
  };

  return config;
})();
```

3_ **for typescript**
create **declarations.d.ts file** with this declare

```
declare module "*.svg" {
    import React from "react";
    import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";
    const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
    export default content;
  }
```

4_ regarding change  **fill property**  :
create file **.svgrrc** and in it

```
{
  "replaceAttrValues": {
    "#000": "{props.fill}"
  }
}
```

And then make sure your path tag inside the SVG file fill attribute is the hex code (in this case #000)

5_ kill terminal and run  npx expo start --clear

here the configuration for expo and react native apps

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer#installation-and-configuration