# am trying tio navigate to SignInScreen i get expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, navigation, components

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Check the render method of `SignInScreen`.

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import LoginSVG from '../assets/images/login.svg';
import GoogleSVG from '../assets/images/google.svg';
import FacebookSVG from '../assets/images/facebook.svg';
import TwitterSVG from '../assets/images/twitter.svg';

import CustomButton from '../components/CustomButton';
import InputField from '../components/InputField';

const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 25}}>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <LoginSVG
          height={300}
          width={300}
          style={{transform: [{rotate: '-5deg'}]}}
        />
      </View>

      <Text
        style={{
          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
          fontSize: 28,
          fontWeight: '500',
          color: '#333',
          marginBottom: 30,
        }}>
        Login
      </Text>

      <InputField
        label={'Email ID'}
        icon={
          <MaterialIcons
          name="alternate-email"
          size={20}
          color="#666"
          style={{marginRight: 5}}
        />
        }
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />

<InputField
        label={'Password'}
        icon={
          <Ionicons
          name="ios-lock-closed-outline"
          size={20}
          color="#666"
          style={{marginRight: 5}}
        />
        }
        inputType="password"
        fieldButtonLabel={"Forgot?"}
        fieldButtonFunction={() => {}}
      />
      
      <CustomButton label={"Login"} onPress={() => {}} />

      <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#666', marginBottom: 30}}>
        Or, login with ...
      </Text>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          marginBottom: 30,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {}}
          style={{
            borderColor: '#ddd',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 30,
            paddingVertical: 10,
          }}>
          <GoogleSVG height={24} width={24} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {}}
          style={{
            borderColor: '#ddd',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 30,
            paddingVertical: 10,
          }}>
          <FacebookSVG height={24} width={24} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {}}
          style={{
            borderColor: '#ddd',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 30,
            paddingVertical: 10,
          }}>
          <TwitterSVG height={24} width={24} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          marginBottom: 30,
        }}>
        <Text>New to the app?</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{color: '#AD40AF', fontWeight: '700'}}> Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default SignInScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the SVGs that you are importing. If you're using `react-native-svg`, you may need to implement [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer) as well. See the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945886/why-am-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-component) for more info

Answer (score 0):

It seems when SVG files are imported like this, they are made available as image sources for `img` tags, not as React components. They need to be converted into React components.

See [Adding SVGs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) from the `create-react-app` docs.

> One way to add SVG files was described in the section above. You can
> also import SVGs directly as React components. You can use either of
> the two approaches. In your code it would look like this:
>
> ```
> import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
>
> function App() {
>   return (
>     <div>
>       {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
>       <Logo />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```

For your code:

```
import { ReactComponent as LoginSVG } from '../assets/images/login.svg';
import { ReactComponent as GoogleSVG } from '../assets/images/google.svg';
import { ReactComponent as FacebookSVG } from '../assets/images/facebook.svg';
import { ReactComponent as TwitterSVG } from '../assets/images/twitter.svg';
```

...

```
<LoginSVG
  height={300}
  width={300}
  style={{transform: [{rotate: '-5deg'}]}}
/>
```